# Create new dataset with maximum values

Tags: stata

This is my dataset in Stata:

[image: Dataset]

I want to create a new dataset that has one row for each patient: the *max* value of `observation`.

---

**EDIT:**

I would also like to keep the `date` variable.

Comment: In the future, please use Stata's `dataex` command to provide us with a [mcve] . Screenshots are not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `collapse` command to get what you want:

```
clear

input patient observation
17133 2.2
17133 2.3
17154 3.2
17154 1.2
17154 2.2
end

collapse (max) observation, by(patient)

list, abbreviate(15)

     +-----------------------+
     | patient   observation |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |   17133           2.3 |
  2. |   17154           3.2 |
     +-----------------------+
```

Type `help collapse` for more details.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the `date` too:

```
clear

input patient observation str10 date1
17133 2.2 "01jul1965"
17133 2.3 "30jun1965"
17144 4.1 "01jul1965"
17144 3.2 "30jun1965"
17144 1.5 "30jun1965"
17154 3.2 "30jun1965"
17154 1.2 "01jul1965"
17154 2.2 "01jul1965"
end

generate date2 = daily(date1, "DMY")
format %tdDDMonCCYY date2

bysort patient (observation): keep if _n == _N

list patient observation date2, abbreviate(15)

     +-----------------------------------+
     | patient   observation       date2 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |   17133           2.3   30Jun1965 |
  2. |   17144           4.1   01Jul1965 |
  3. |   17154           3.2   30Jun1965 |
     +-----------------------------------+
```